# How do I capitalize and sort my input in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My code needs the 5 words that I put in to always be in alphabetical order and I am not sure how to do it.

I already have the upcase and downcase taken care of but I also need it to sort the words I put in at the same time.

Here is what I have so far:

```
tasks = []
5.times do 
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  tasks << gets.chomp
end

puts "Here are your words:" 

tasks.each_with_index do |team, index|
  if index.even?
    puts team.upcase
  else
    puts team.downcase
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please make an example of input and desired output? It is not clear what you want to get as a result.

Comment: tasks = []

5.times do 
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  tasks << gets.chomp
end
puts "Here are your words:" 
tasks.each_with_index do |team, index|
  if index.even?
    puts team.upcase
  else
    puts team.downcase
  end
end

Comment: I need the 5 words that will be entered to be alphabetized. I am not sure how I would go about to do that. Its a little hard to explain

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question it's important to take the time to format it so it's readable to those trying to help you. It shows us, who are taking the time to help you, that you took the time too. Please read the help for the editor, including the advanced help as its your friend.

Comment: What is "alphabetize"?

Comment: Like in alphabetical order. I am not sure how else to say it lol

Comment: It's not clear if you want to upcase/downcase before or after the sort and whether you want the sort to be case-sensitive (`"Z"<"a" #=> true`). Suppose the strings entered were "fee", "Fii", "foo", "Fum". If you upcase/downcase before the sort and make the sort to be case-sensitive, you'd get `["FEE", "FOO", "fii", "fum"]`. If you make the sort case-insensitive and upcase/downcase after the sort, you'd get `["FEE", "fii", "FOO", "fum"]`. These are the sorts of examples @Alexey was requesting. Please answer him by editing your question, rather than replying in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
tasks.each_with_index
```

to

```
tasks.sort.each_with_index
```

---

A better rewrite of the whole code is:

```
tasks = Array.new(5) do 
  puts "Please enter a word:"
  gets.chomp
end
puts "Here are your words:" 
tasks.sort.each_slice(2) do |even, odd|
  puts even.upcase, *(odd.downcase if odd)
end
```

Comment: Maybe `puts even.upcase, odd.to_s.downcase`

Comment: @steenslag That may add an extra line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the sort to be case-insensitive and want to upcase/downcase after the entries are sorted, you could do this:

```
which = [:upcase, :downcase].cycle
5.times.map { gets.chomp }.
        sort_by(&:downcase).
        map { |s| s.send(which.next) }
```

If the entries were "The", "cat", "and", "the", "hat", this would return:

```
["CAT", "hat", "IN", "the", "THE"]
```

Comment: You seem to like `cycle`. I agree with your point regarding `sort_by(&:downcase)`.

Comment: @sawa, yes on `cycle`. I like to reduce the numbers of block variables when I can. I made a small improvement with my `cycle` here.

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) on the array:

```
tasks.sort.each_with_index do |team, index|
  # ...
```

I advise to read in the docs about all the other useful methods on arrays and other core classes.